# Can a SELECT be run in a loop in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql, loops, select

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT PartnerPk FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Realm="aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd" ;
```

Where "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd" should come from a 2881 lines text file.

**In MySQL, can I create a loop that will run the SELECT on each "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd" in the file, and write the resulting output to a text file?**

Alternately, can I create a (long) single query that retrieves all these values with only a single table scan (since the table scan will apparently take a minute or two)?

Note:  my MySQL server is running with the `--read-only` option

Comment: What exactly does *Where "aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd" should come from a 2881 lines text file* mean? Can you please show a portion of the file and explain how its contents should be used?

Comment: Not exactly. You can `load`/import the text file into a table. Let's call it table `test` and column `realm`. Then, you can do `select .. from customer c where exists (select 1 from test where realm = c.realm);`

Comment: Do you want to use the `IN()` predicate to search for a list of values? Cf. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_in Anyway, MySQL cannot read a file to get values for a query. It is typically easy to write some code in some client application to do this sort of task.

Comment: And you could also use `SELECT PartnerPk FROM CUSTOMER WHERE Realm IN ("aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd", "eee.fff.ggg.hhh" ... )`

Comment: Thanks, @nacho, I'll construct that (long) query, and see if it'll work.